# how to backup and restore postgresql data from remote to local system in single command

Tags: postgresql

I have to take database dump from remote server but i want to download it on my local system and then restore it directly on my local system with using a single command. actually my remote server disk is full so i can't take data bakup there.

Comment: Use `pg_dump`. It is a client tool and writes the dump to the filesystem from where it is started

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup-dump.html

Comment: @MilenA.Radev: is there any command to dump and restore in one file without creating a file. something llike pipelining concept. and can we restore with dir format in the ssame way that we do other formats like tar.

Comment: Yes, there is such an example on the page I linked.

Comment: @MilenA.Radev: i don't know where is that example. would you paste that example here and give brief description.other thing is my postgresql server is production server with huge data and it is not allowing tcp/ip connection . i can't change postgresql.conf as it would require restart + it is on server. any help in that

Answer (score 2):

You can use a pipe for this:

```
pg_dump -f -  ... | psql -f - ...
```

or:

```
pg_dump -Fc -f - ... | pg_restore -f -   ....
```

The `-f -` parameter (which is actually the default for `pg_dump`, but included for clarity) tells the command to write to stdout / read from stdin as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Install pg_dump in one of your local system and run the following command from your local system

```
pg_dump -h your_remort_syten's_ip -U username database_name > /home/user/Desktop/dump_db.sql
```

I think this will help u.

Comment: thanks. is there any command to directly restore wihout creating a bakup file. like one line command to backup and then restore.

Comment: @user3143770 - just pipe pg_dump to pg_restore